# Unexpected behaviour Redux navigating on store change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a problem which I cannot seem to resolve.
I have two screens: HomeScreen and Mapscreen, I navigate from HomeScreen to Mapscreen. In MapScreen I change a state in my store using this code:

```
 const mapSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'map',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setStateCoordinates(state, {payload}) {
      state.zoomLevel = payload.zoom;
      state.center_coordinate = payload.center;
    },
  },
});
```

I created a dummy component to pin down the problem,
Here is how I call the store:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

import {View, Button} from 'react-native';
import {setStateCoordinates, toggleRefresh} from '../features/map/mapSlice';
const mapDispatch = {
  setStateCoordinates,
  toggleRefresh,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state;
}

const TestComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={{width: 60, height: 60, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <Button
        style={{widt: 40, height: 40}}
        onPress={() => {
          props.setStateCoordinates({zoom: 8.8, center: [4.2, 6.3]});
        }}
        title="Test"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatch)(TestComponent);
```

Edit: here is my store config

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  menu: menuSlice,
  menutoggle: pintpointSlice,
  data: dataSlice,
  map: mapSlice,
  user: userSlice,
  trail: trailSlice,
  customPin: customPinSlice,
  stat: statSlice,
});
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

**The store does change !** My problem is that for some reasons after changing it chooses to navigate (or render) Homescreen instead of the screen it has been called from (MapScreen).

Upon changes the view navigate back to HomeScreen. I'm using "react-redux": "7.1.3", "redux": "4.0.5", react-native: 0.64

If you have any lead please help me, I've been struggling for days...

Comment: It might be more interesting to see the component where you do the routing. Nothing with this code is inherently wrong, although usage of `connect` with a function component is a bit "outdated". The official recommendation is to use `useSelector` and `useDispatch` whenever possible. But that will not trigger your bug here ;)

Comment: @phry thank you for your response, i am not sure what you asked for so i edited with the store config. I don't have much routing beside 'connect' and dispatch into reducers.
Thanks for the advice, i'll definetly check useSelector and useDispatch :)

Comment: well, at some point you probably have some logic whether you display `HomeScreen` or `Mapscreen` - that is what I meant with "routing"